# Insert XML data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert "DocumentFields" values from XML into SQL Server 2008 but no luck.

Can you please help me with this? Below is the XML and the stored procedure used.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]
   (@xmlData As XML)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idoc int

    SET @xmlData='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ImportSession>
     <Documents>
      <Document DocumentClassName="RDOCCLASS" Processed="0" Priority="2">
       <DocumentFields>
        <DocumentField Name="DocumentID" Value="419" />
        <DocumentField Name="MessageID" Value="apap-12w-asqwe" />
        <DocumentField Name="AccountName" Value="John Thomas" />
        <DocumentField Name="AccountNumber" Value="1234567890" />
        <DocumentField Name="Contact" Value="00012736782345" />
       </DocumentFields>
      </Document>
     </Documents>
    </ImportSession>'

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlData;

    INSERT INTO  dbo.[Account]([DocumentID], [MessageID], [AccountName], [AccountNumber], [Contact])
        SELECT * 
        FROM OPENXML(@idoc,/ImportSession/Documents/Document/DocumentFields',1)
        WITH (DocumentID varchar(20),MessageID varchar(30),
         AccountName varchar(20),AccountNumber varchar(20),
         Contact varchar(20)
         );

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmlData;
END
```

Thanks
Arsh

Comment: No luck... details please. In what way does it not work? Getting an error? If so include the error message in your question.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3):

OPENXML is absolutely outdated. This is the way you get the data from your XML variable in a modern way:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ImportSession>
     <Documents>
      <Document DocumentClassName="RDOCCLASS" Processed="0" Priority="2">
       <DocumentFields>
        <DocumentField Name="DocumentID" Value="419" />
        <DocumentField Name="MessageID" Value="apap-12w-asqwe" />
        <DocumentField Name="AccountName" Value="John Thomas" />
        <DocumentField Name="AccountNumber" Value="1234567890" />
        <DocumentField Name="Contact" Value="00012736782345" />
       </DocumentFields>
      </Document>
     </Documents>
    </ImportSession>';

SELECT Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="DocumentID"]/@Value)[1]','int') AS DocumentID
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="MessageID"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS MessageID
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="AccountName"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS AccountName
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="AccountNumber"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS AccountNumber
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="Contact"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Contact
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ImportSession/Documents/Document') AS One(Doc)
```

So your SP should be this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]
 (
    @xmlData As XML
 )

As
BEGIN



 INSERT INTO  dbo.[Account]([DocumentID],
                           [MessageID],
                           [AccountName],
                           [AccountNumber],
                           [Contact]
                          )

SELECT Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="DocumentID"]/@Value)[1]','int') AS DocumentID
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="MessageID"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS MessageID
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="AccountName"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS AccountName
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="AccountNumber"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS AccountNumber
      ,Doc.value('(DocumentFields/DocumentField[@Name="Contact"]/@Value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Contact
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ImportSession/Documents/Document') AS One(Doc);
END
```

Comment: Ah, no pivoting needed the way you do it. =)

Comment: If I would mess around with my answer, I would probably turn up with yours =). I deleted it. I was trying to get a "document" number in there, but I don't want to mess around with a numbers table. Yours is more elegant. I still have much to learn ;-)

Comment: @TT. You lost my upvote by deleting this. Poor you! I just placed a vote on another answer of yours to keep the damage away from you :-)

Comment: Oh I don't mind that, I'd rather be correct any day! =) Anyway I gained more insight from your answer, that's most important.

Comment: @TT Oh I *do* mind that. I'm kind of adicted with collecting rep points. But you are right: In the months I'm contributing here I've learned incredibly much. Especially in such a case, were you place an answer and another answer is somehow better / more elegant / more performant one can learn best...

Comment: Great thanks lot Shnugo. Given solution is working fine.